# SQL Performance With Not Equals before Equals and vice versa

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql queries and trying to learn as much as I can about them.Here is the SQL query I'm flirting with right now and have some questions about it.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count 
FROM stride 
WHERE recipientId = ? 
   AND recipientView = 0 
   AND sourceUserId != recipientId
```

1. Does it make a performance difference to put the equals before the not equals or vice versa?
2. I am using recipientId twice here. Is it better to call the variable the second time or should I fill the variable both times? For example.

`SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM stride WHERE recipientId = ? AND recipientView = 0 AND sourceUserId != ?`

1. `id` is the primary key. Does it make any difference performance wise to put `COUNT(*)` instead? I feel like doing `COUNT(id)` would be faster but it's just a feeling and I have no proof.
2. Should I use `IN` or any other operators here instead to gain query speed?
3. Is there anything you would do here to make this query faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query optimization has very little to do with the syntax of your query and a lot to do with the RDMS query optimizer.

All of the things you suggest will probably make *no* difference whatsoever as the optimizer will pull them apart and build what it feels is the best query. Specifically,

1. Doesn't matter
2. Doesn't matter
3. No performance impact but note that `COUNT(id)<>COUNT(*)` if there are `NULL`s in the id column - for a primary key there won't be any `NULL`s.
4. I can't see how you could build this query with an `IN` but in any event it will not impact performance
5. Indexes impact speed dramatically - for this query, indexes on `recipientId`, `recipientView` and `sourceUserId` will have dramatic impacts

What you should do is not take my word for it. Set up each of the queries and look at the execution plan from the RDMS. If they are the same there, then they are the same query.

Comment: How do I do the last bit you talk about in phpMyAdmin? How can I test these queries?

Comment: Read the documentation - my experience is with SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

it will not matter where the equals and not equal are located - unless there are subqueries. In your case the where clause will be evaluated as a whole so it does not matter where the not equal and equals are.

Count(id) vs Count(*) is the same since [id] is your primary key. There is no performance advantage in either count.